# Generalise ansible commands after python upgrade in 5.x node

Tags: ansible

I have many systems connected to my Ansible server which are in CentOS 5.X and CentOS 6.X. I have upgraded python of CentOS 5.x to 2.6 version and created a soft link as below to work Ansible in CentOS 5.x nodes:

```
# ll /usr/local/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Jan 12 22:36 /usr/local/python -> /opt/python2.6/bin/python
```

Now I am running ansible-playbook commands as below:

```
# Centos 5.x:
ansible-playbook copy.yml -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/python'

# Centos 6.x: 
ansible-playbook copy.yml
```

In order to generalize the command for both CentOS 5.x and CentOS 6.x systems, I decided to map my Python path as environmental variable.

What should be the entries of .bash_profile for that? Is there another solution?

Comment: "*What should be the entries of .bash_profile for that?*" -- this won't work. `.bash_profile` is not sourced for non-interactive SSH sessions with Ansible use.

Comment: ok..is there another solution?

Comment: Ansible doesn't know what the system is until it gathers facts. To gather facts, it requires Python (hence the path). You can use `raw` module to check, but that's not feasible.　・　Simply define it in the inventory. You know what systems you manage and what versions they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to use inventory.

Something like this:

```
[centos5]
host1
host2

[centos5:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/python

[centos6]
host3
host4
```

This way `ansible_python_interpreter` will be overridden only for centos5 hosts.